# Unlocking Bootloader without OEM unlocking and fastboot

Tags: android, bootloader, samsung

I have installed a custom ROM (PixelOS) on my Samsung Note 10 which does not have OEM unlocking option in Developer Options. Also Samsung does not have fastboot so that is also out of question. Is there any way that I can unlock the bootloader without OEM unlocking and fastboot mode.

I have PixelOS recovery installed which has an option of fastboot but the command "fastboot devices" does not list anything on PC.

Comment: If you have a custom ROM installed your bootloader should be already unlocked.